# About styling order list

Tags: html, css

```
<html>
<head>

<style type='text/css'>
ol li{background-color:green;}
ol li:hover{background-color:lightgreen;}
</style>

</head>

<body>

<ol>
  <li>This is first line</li>
  <li>Here is second line</li>
  <li>And last line</li>
</ol>

</body>
</html>
```

if we use this coding the number's background color is not changing when we mouse over. i want to change the number's background color too when we mouse over, how can we do it.

Comment: I'm not seeing a number in the first place in Chrome:  http://jsfiddle.net/yLzLx/

Comment: @Pekka, if you untick the 'normalized css' the numbers show up.

Answer (score 4):

You've got a couple of options, the first is to use: `list-style-position: inside;`:

```
ol li{background-color:green; list-style-position: inside;}
ol li:hover{background-color:lightgreen;}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/yLzLx/2/).

And the second is to use generated content:

```
ol {
    counter-reset: listNumber;
}
ol li {background-color:green; list-style-type: none; counter-increment: listNumber; position: relative; }
ol li:before {
    content: counter(listNumber);
    background-color: green;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: -2em;
    width: 1.6em;
    display: block;
}
ol li:hover,
ol li:hover:before {background-color:lightgreen;}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/yLzLx/3/).

The latter approach, using generated content, is probably the better approach but with weaker cross-browser support; as [it fails in IE<8 (though is supported in IE8+)](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html#t15).

Answer (score 0):

not only list-style-position should be used, but also text-indent
http://jsfiddle.net/HerrSerker/QtRwa/

```
ol {
    list-style-position: inside;
    padding-left: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}
ol li {
    background-color:green;
    text-indent: -20px;
    padding-left: 20px;
}
```